# Getting Status code 422 when creating Kubernetes Job using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I am creating a Kubernetes Job within NodeJS class After importing the library `@kubernetes/client-node`, I created an object to use the module `BatchV1Api` inside the function which I am exporting to other class in which I have defined the body of the Kubernetes job like this:

//listJobs.js

```
import { post } from '../kubeClient.js';

const kubeRoute = async (ctx) => {
    const newJob = {
        metadata: {
            name: 'countdown',
        },
        spec: {
            template: {
                metadata: {
                    name: 'countdown',
                },
            },
            spec: {
                containers: [
                    {
                        name: 'counter',
                        image: 'centos:7',
                        command: 'bin/bash, -c, for i in 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ; do echo $i ; done',
                    }],
                restartPolicy: 'Never',
            },
        },
    };

    const kubeClient = post();
    kubeClient.createNamespacedJob('default', newJob);
    ctx.body = {
        // listConfigMap: (await kubeClient.listConfigMapForAllNamespaces()).body,
        listJobs: (await kubeClient.listJobForAllNamespaces()).body,
        // listService: (await kubeClient.listServiceForAllNamespaces()).body,
    };
};

export default kubeRoute;
```

Then I created a router class to request the post method like:

```
import post from './listJobs.js';

const apiRouter = new Router();
apiRouter.post('/api/v1/newJob', post);
```

when executing the application and requesting the route `localhost:3000/api/v1/newJob` as a post request in postman, it is showing status code `422` (with some very long output, as in the screenshot) in the vs code terminal and some Kubernetes information in postman body, but it is not creating any job or pod.

[image: KubeJobTerminalError]

Does anyone have any idea, why there is `422` code at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code 422 **Unprocessable Entity** means that server understand the content type, and the syntax of the request is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.

In your case though, the Job manifest looks off.

I'm not an expert in JavaScript kubernetes client, but `newJob` body looks weird. The resulting yaml should look like this

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: countdown
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: counter
        image: centos:7
        command: 'bin/bash, -c, for i in {9..1} ; do echo $i ; done' #fixed this one for you
      restartPolicy: Never
```

In your case the second `spec` is a child of `spec`. It should be a child of `template`, so:

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "countdown"
  },
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "counter",
            "image": "centos:7",
            "command": "bin/bash, -c, for i in {9..1} ; do echo $i ; done"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Never"
      }
    }
  }
}
```