# Ansible kubernetes module fails to use kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am writing an Ansible playbook that uses the `kubernetes` module to modify a `ConfigMap` entry on my cluster. An important caveat to note is that I am running a docker image that contains an Ansible installation to do this work. I run the docker image and hand it the necessary inputs for it to do its job. Here is an example of the run command:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -e ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/play-config/ansible.cfg -e K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG=/play-config/gagnon.config -e K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT=kubernetes-admin@kubernetes -v "C:\Users\jgagnon\gagnon-test\local-kube-prometheus-stack\ansible":/play-config cytopia/ansible:latest-tools
```

Then, in the running container:

```
$ ansible-playbook /play-config/playbook-arc-control-plane.yaml -u jgagnon
```

After some initial hurdles, where I found that some missing dependencies needed to be installed on the target cluster nodes, I believe I have satisfied dependency requirements. Now I'm running into a problem where the playbook fails when it attempts to make the ConfigMap change using `kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch`. I have tried a number of things to see if I could correct the problem, to no avail. I keep getting an error:

```
"msg": "Failed to load kubeconfig due to Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found."
```

Here is the play (from playbook-arc-control-plane.yaml):

```
- name: "Make kube-proxy visible to Prometheus"
  hosts: control_planes

  become_user: root
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: "Install pip"
      shell:
        cmd: "apt-get install -y python3-pip"

    - name: "Install jsonpatch"
      shell:
        cmd: "apt-get install -y python3-jsonpatch"

    - name: "Install kubernetes Ansible module"
      pip:
        name:
          kubernetes

    - debug:
        var: lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG')
    - debug:
        var: lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT')

    - name: "Patch kube-proxy ConfigMap metricsBindAddress"
      kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch:
        kind: ConfigMap
        name: kube-proxy
        namespace: kube-system
        context: "{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT') }}"
        kubeconfig: "{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG') }}"
        patch:
          - op: replace
            path: /data/config.conf/metricsBindAddress
            value: 0.0.0.0
```

Here is a section of the playbook console output (`-vvv` flag was specified):

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /play-config/playbook-arc-control-plane.yaml:180
ok: [gagnon-m1] => {
    "lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG')": "/play-config/gagnon.config"
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /play-config/playbook-arc-control-plane.yaml:182
ok: [gagnon-m1] => {
    "lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT')": "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes"
}

TASK [Patch kube-proxy ConfigMap metricsBindAddress] *******************************************************************************************
task path: /play-config/playbook-arc-control-plane.yaml:185
...
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch_payload_aqz5jjfp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/common.py", line 256, in get_api_client
    _load_config()
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch_payload_aqz5jjfp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/common.py", line 218, in _load_config
    kubernetes.config.load_kube_config(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 813, in load_kube_config
    loader = _get_kube_config_loader(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 770, in _get_kube_config_loader
    raise ConfigException(
fatal: [gagnon-m1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null,
            "api_version": "v1",
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "context": "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes",
            "host": null,
            "impersonate_groups": null,
            "impersonate_user": null,
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "kubeconfig": "/play-config/gagnon.config",
            "name": "kube-proxy",
            "namespace": "kube-system",
            "no_proxy": null,
            "password": null,
            "patch": [
                {
                    "op": "replace",
                    "path": "/data/config.conf/metricsBindAddress",
                    "value": "0.0.0.0"
                }
            ],
            "persist_config": null,
            "proxy": null,
            "proxy_headers": null,
            "username": null,
            "validate_certs": null,
            "wait": false,
            "wait_condition": null,
            "wait_sleep": 5,
            "wait_timeout": 120
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to load kubeconfig due to Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found."
}
```

I've verified the referenced kubeconfig file (`/play-config/gagnon.config`) exists in the container. Also, I have been using this config file for months with no problem, so I'm pretty sure it's valid.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong? I assume I have met all dependencies, otherwise I wouldn't expect this task to run at all (or at least fail for a different reason).

**UPDATE**:

I suspect, but have not been able to verify, that the problem stems from an incorrect path specified in the `kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch` command.

If you dump a ConfigMap as JSON, the data is not represented as JSON, but rather as just a string.

For example:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "config.conf": "apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1\nbindAddress: 0.0.0.0\nbindAddressHardFail: false\nclientConnection:\n  acceptContentTypes: \"\"\n  burst: 0\n  contentType: \"\"\n  kubeconfig: /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf\n  qps: 0\nclusterCIDR: \"\"\nconfigSyncPeriod: 0s\nconntrack:\n  maxPerCore: null\n  min: null\n  tcpCloseWaitTimeout: null\n  tcpEstablishedTimeout: null\ndetectLocal:\n  bridgeInterface: \"\"\n  interfaceNamePrefix: \"\"\ndetectLocalMode: \"\"\nenableProfiling: false\nhealthzBindAddress: \"\"\nhostnameOverride: \"\"\niptables:\n  masqueradeAll: false\n  masqueradeBit: null\n  minSyncPeriod: 0s\n  syncPeriod: 0s\nipvs:\n  excludeCIDRs: null\n  minSyncPeriod: 0s\n  scheduler: \"\"\n  strictARP: false\n  syncPeriod: 0s\n  tcpFinTimeout: 0s\n  tcpTimeout: 0s\n  udpTimeout: 0s\nkind: KubeProxyConfiguration\nmetricsBindAddress: 0.0.0.0\nmode: \"\"\nnodePortAddresses: null\noomScoreAdj: null\nportRange: \"\"\nshowHiddenMetricsForVersion: \"\"\nudpIdleTimeout: 0s\nwinkernel:\n  enableDSR: false\n  forwardHealthCheckVip: false\n  networkName: \"\"\n  rootHnsEndpointName: \"\"\n  sourceVip: \"\"",
        "kubeconfig.conf": "apiVersion: v1\nkind: Config\nclusters:\n- cluster:\n    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt\n    server: https://172.20.8.68:6443\n  name: default\ncontexts:\n- context:\n    cluster: default\n    namespace: default\n    user: default\n  name: default\ncurrent-context: default\nusers:\n- name: default\n  user:\n    tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"
    },
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubeadm.kubernetes.io/component-config.hash": "sha256:aa87680dfe2321f98df103555d18d439916b19e0bf23bd0f98bb3e27c5adfc08"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-08-22T12:08:21Z",
        "labels": {
            "app": "kube-proxy"
        },
        "name": "kube-proxy",
        "namespace": "kube-system",
        "resourceVersion": "21706920",
        "uid": "97594de0-5aaa-4ea0-bd8c-a2f5fb357be7"
    }
}
```

I am trying to modify the value of the `metricsBindAddress` field contained within the `config.conf` item in the `ConfigMap` data. The example provided above has the path specified as `/data/config.conf/metricsBindAddress`. I think this is why the failure is occurring.

To test my theory, I changed the path to `/data[config.conf]metricsBindAddress`. I had no idea what would happen, but to my surprise, it did not throw an error. However, it also did not change the field of interest. Progress, though.

I don't know the correct way to specify a path to get to what I need in the context of the Ansible `kubernetes` module.

Comment: is the config file `/play-config/gagnon.config` in the `control_planes` host?

Comment: No it's on the "ansible node" (i.e. the docker container). The `-v` option is making my PC local directory available to the container so that it has the playbook and whatever else it needs. That's a separate topic that I have questions/concerns about.

Comment: if it is inside the docker container, it won't be reachable; would you try with a copy of the `gagnon.config` located in the `gagnon-m1` host?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I tried that and it got past that error. Now it's complaining that it couldn't patch the object. It's passing a code of 422 and the message is "Unprocessable Entity". Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Is it an error like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848511/getting-status-code-422-when-creating-kubernetes-job-using-nodejs ? they fixed it with changes in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With helpful insight from [Carlos Monroy Nieblas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6812035/carlos-monroy-nieblas), I was able to figure out what needed to be done differently. The `K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG` environment variable specified in the docker run command needed to point to a `kubeconfig` file located on the kubernetes node, not the Ansible node.

I also found through another source that I needed to modify how I approached getting and modifying the `ConfigMap` entry. The "data" in a ConfigMap entry is a string and needs to be pulled as a whole, modified and re-inserted into the map.

The docker run command is now:

```
docker run --rm -it -e ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/play-config/ansible.cfg -e K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG=/home/jgagnon/.kube/config -v "C:\Users\jgagnon\gagnon-test\local-kube-prometheus-stack\ansible":/play-config cytopia/ansible:latest-tools ansible-playbook /play-config/playbook-arc-control-plane.yaml -u jgagnon
```

The play is now:

```
- name: "Make kube-proxy visible to Prometheus"
  hosts: control_planes
  # hosts: arc-master-1

  become_user: root
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: "Install pip"
      shell:
        cmd: "apt-get install -y python3-pip"

    - name: "Install jsonpatch"
      shell:
        cmd: "apt-get install -y python3-jsonpatch"

    - name: "Install kubernetes Ansible module"
      pip:
        name:
          kubernetes

    - name: "Get kube-proxy ConfigMap"
      kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
        kind: ConfigMap
        name: kube-proxy
        namespace: kube-system
        kubeconfig: "{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG') }}"
      register: kube_proxy_data

    - name: "Patch kube-proxy ConfigMap metricsBindAddress"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        new_data: "{{ kube_proxy_data.resources[0].data['config.conf'] |
                      from_yaml | combine(patch) }}"
      vars:
        patch:
          "metricsBindAddress": "0.0.0.0"

    - name: "Replace kube-proxy config.conf data"
      kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch:
        kind: ConfigMap
        name: kube-proxy
        namespace: kube-system
        kubeconfig: "{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG') }}"
        patch:
          - op: replace
            path: /data/config.conf
            value: "{{ new_data | to_nice_yaml(indent=2, width=120) }}"
```